# Using the xstack filter in ffmpeg

Tags: python, video

[image]

The xstack filter allows to build a mosaic video file with ffmpeg.

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#xstack

To automate its usage, I wrote a script that takes video files with unmatched resolutions, durations and ratios, and used letterboxing to fit them and encode it with only 2 stages, for video and audio. I did not want to have intermediate files, so it works with only 3 stages (scan, convert, mix_audio). I'm not sure if it would execute faster if it used intermediates files.

To spread and "balance" videos across 4 segments of similar length, I use a bin packing algorithm:

```
1. Have 4 mosaic lists of video segments
2. Pick the longest video segment among non-inserted segments
3. Insert it into the mosaic segment list that has the shortest duration length.
4. repeat step 2 and 3 until all video has been inserted
```

The code is not the cleanest, but I used it several times and I think it works well enough. The script generates a ffmpeg command dump to inspect if it follows good "ffmpeg practices" for each filter. Video encoding is not my specialty, and I worked several times to fix audio/video desync problems, SAR/DAR issues, and to make letterboxing work, which was not easy to understand, and folks on #ffmpeg on libera and stackoverflow helped me a lot.

This script also generates a HTML report for every video file, that shows codecs, SAR/DAR, resolutions, durations, etc.

Apart from the obvious messiness, I wanted to know if there are possible improvements to this script, and if someones thinks there are better ways to do this. I'm not 100% sure it's using ffmpeg correctly, since it's not always easy to listen to desyncs or to spot for problems. This command often generates warnings, but I'm not sure they're serious.

Feel free to test it!

There are other python script that handle ffmpeg, but I don't think they can really do everything this script does (I haven't really tried those other scripts in details, but I'm guessing they have limitations).

```
from os import listdir as ls
from shutil import copyfile as cp
from sys import argv
import subprocess
from pprint import pformat
import os, sys
import time
import datetime
import random

################ REQUIREMENTS ################
ffmpeg = r"c:/ffmpeg.exe"
ffprobe = r"c:/ffprobe.exe"

'''
################ USAGE ################
0. ALL VIDEO FILES MUST HAVE AN AUDIO TRACK
1. python ffmpeg-mosaic.py <VIDEO FOLDER PATH> scan
    Scans for video files, generates a HTML file to spot files without audio
2. python ffmpeg-mosaic.py <VIDEO FOLDER PATH> convert
    Video processing
    For powershell users, use a folder with short paths to be below the CMD BATCH size limit.
3. python ffmpeg-mosaic.py <VIDEO FOLDER PATH> mix_audio <VIDEO FOLDER PATH>\xstacked\<THE XSTACK VIDEO FILE>
    Does the same thing for audio, and merge audio and video. This stage is of course much faster
'''

def lessshortdate():
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S")
def shortdate():
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M")
def sizeof_fmt(num, suffix=''):
    for unit in ['','K','M','G','T','P','E','Z']:
        if abs(num) < 1024.0:
            numpart = "%.1f"%num
            if numpart[-2:] == '.0' or num >99: numpart = numpart[:-2]
            return "%s %s%s" % (numpart, unit, suffix)
            # return "%3.1f%s%s" % (num, unit, suffix)
        num /= 1024.0

    numpart = "%.1f"%num
    if numpart[-2:] == '.0': numpart = numpart[:-2]
    return "%s %s%s" % (numpart, 'Y', suffix)



# for html generation
def html_start(f, css=''):
    f.write("<html><head>")
    f.write("<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />")
    f.write('''
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        const getCellValue = (tr, idx) => tr.children[idx].innerText || tr.children[idx].textContent;

        const comparer = (idx, asc) => (a, b) => ((v1, v2) =>
            v1 !== '' && v2 !== '' && !isNaN(v1) && !isNaN(v2) ? v1 - v2 : v1.toString().localeCompare(v2)
            )(getCellValue(asc ? a : b, idx), getCellValue(asc ? b : a, idx));

        // do the work...
        document.querySelectorAll('th').forEach(th => th.addEventListener('click', (() => {
            const table = th.closest('table');
            Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(n+2)'))
                .sort(comparer(Array.from(th.parentNode.children).indexOf(th), this.asc = !this.asc))
                .forEach(tr => table.appendChild(tr) );
        })));
};
</script>''')

    f.write('''<style type='text/css'>
    .b{font-size:150%;} .b1{font-size:150%;} .b2{font-size:200%;} .b3{font-size:250%;}
    .s{font-size:75%;} .s1{font-size:50%;} .s2{font-size:25%;} .s3{font-size:75%;}
    .s3{font-size:50%;vertical-align:middle;}
    .al{vertical-align:middle;}
    .bgf{background: #bbb;}
    .r{text-align: left; font-family: sans-serif;}
    .node{padding-left:2px;padding-top:2px; border:1px solid black;float:right;}
    #w span { cursor: pointer; }
    #w span:hover { color:orange; }
    #w span:visited { color:green; }
    #w span:active { color:red; }
    .constantwidth {width:1000px; height:auto;}
    ''' + css +
    '''
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    ''')

def html_finish(f):
    f.write("</body></html>")
    f.close()


stage = sys.argv[2] if len(sys.argv) > 2 else None

def shfn(s, maxsize = 32):
    # if len(s)-a-b < 8:
    if len(s) < maxsize:
        return s
    return s[:int(maxsize*0.75)]+u'…'+s[-int(maxsize*0.25):]

# getting video info data
def get_info(path):
    # proc = subprocess.run([ffprobe]+args, stdout = subprocess.DEVNULL)

    # first show_format
    args = ["-show_format", "-print_format", "json", "-i", path]

    proc = subprocess.run([ffprobe]+args, capture_output=True)
    result = proc.stdout.decode("utf-8")
    show_format = eval(result)
    show_format = show_format['format']

    # print(show_format)
    if False: # spamming the terminal
        print(show_format['filename'])
        for a,b in show_format.items():
            print('    ', a, '\t', b)

    # then show_streams
    video = None
    audio = None

    args = ["-show_streams", "-print_format", "json", "-i", path]
    proc = subprocess.run([ffprobe]+args, capture_output=True)
    result = proc.stdout.decode("utf-8")
    streams = eval(result)
    streams = streams['streams']

    # print(len(streams))
    if len(streams) < 2:
        if 'codec_type' in streams[0] and streams[0]['codec_type'] == 'audio':
            return None, None
        video = streams[0]

    else:
        if 'codec_type' in streams[0]:
            if streams[0]['codec_type'] == 'audio':
                audio = streams[0]
            elif streams[0]['codec_type'] == 'video':
                video = streams[0]

        if 'codec_type' in streams[1]:
            if streams[1]['codec_type'] == 'audio':
                audio = streams[1]
            elif streams[1]['codec_type'] == 'video':
                video = streams[1]


    filename = os.path.basename(path)

    ret = {}
    # a if cond else b
    if 'duration' in video:
        ret['dur'] = time.strftime('%M:%S', time.gmtime(float(video['duration'])))
        ret['duration'] = float(video['duration'])
    elif 'duration' in show_format:
        ret['dur'] = time.strftime('%M:%S', time.gmtime(float(show_format['duration'])))
        ret['duration'] = float(show_format['duration'])
    elif 'tags' in video and 'DURATION' in video['tags']:
        ret['dur'] = video['tags']['DURATION']
        ret['duration'] = video['tags']['DURATION']
    else:
        ret['dur'] = '-'
        ret['duration'] = '-'


    if 'width' in video:
        ret['dim'] = str(video['width'])+'x'+str(video['height'])
        dim2 = (video['width'], video['height'])
        ret['ratio'] = str(round(dim2[0] / dim2[1], 3))
    else:
        ret['ratio'] = '-'
        ret['dim'] = '-'
    # ret['dur'] = time.strftime('%M:%S', time.gmtime(float(video['duration'])))
    # ret['dur'] = time.strftime('%M:%S', time.gmtime(float(dic['duration'])))
    ret['filesize'] = sizeof_fmt(os.path.getsize(path))
    # print(path)

    if 'avg_frame_rate' in video:
        framerate = video['avg_frame_rate']
        try:
            framerate_f = round(float(int(framerate.split('/')[0]) / int(framerate.split('/')[1])),3)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print(filename, framerate)
        framerate = "%s %s"%(str(framerate_f),framerate)
    else:
        framerate = '-'

    ret['framerate'] = framerate ### removed
    ret['codec'] = video['codec_name'] ### removed
    # ret['framerate'] = video['avg_frame_rate'] ### removed
    ret['audio'] = audio['codec_name'] if audio != None else '-'

    ret['filename'] = filename
    ret['path'] = path


    # ret['pix_fmt'] = video['pix_fmt'] ## removed

    # ret['ratio'] = video['display_aspect_ratio'].split(':')
    # ret['ratio'] = str(int(ret['ratio'][0])/int(ret['ratio'][1]))


    # print(ret)
    # print('finished')




    return ret, result

# printing a dict with return lines
def dirtyformat(dic):
    s = repr(dic)
    s = s.replace('{','{\n').replace('}', '}\n\n')
    return s

# html report
def write_html(data):
    tag = lambda s, t: "<%s>%s</%s>\n"%(t,s,t)
    trth = lambda ar: tag(''.join([tag(a, 'th') for a in ar]), 'tr')
    table = lambda s: tag(s, 'table')
    tr = lambda ar: tag(''.join([tag(a, 'td') for a in ar]), 'tr')



    keys = []
    for filename,stuff in data.items():
        # keys = stuff.keys()
        keys = [a for a,b in (stuff).items() if a != 'path']
        break

    # for filename,stuff in data.items():
    for a,b in data.items():
        b['filename'] = shfn(b['filename'],64)

    ar = [[b for a,b in (stuff).items() if a != 'path'] for filename, stuff in data.items()]
    # print(ar)
    # print(keys)
    f = open(argv[1]+"\\xstacked\\vid_data.nogit.html",'w', encoding = 'utf-8')
    html_start(f)

    f.write(table(
        trth(keys)+''.join([tr(line) for line in ar])
    ))

    html_finish(f)

# gathering video info, either scan or opening saved scan
def gather_vid_info(path, stage, segments_limit = False):
    print("###### PLEASE CHECK IF ALL FILES GOT AUDIO FIRST ! ######")
    import os
    from pprint import pformat
    vid_data = {}
    print('scanning dir', path)
    if 'file_list' in sys.argv:
        pass
    if stage == 'scan':
        raw = open(sys.argv[1]+"\\xstacked\\stdout.nogit.txt",'w',encoding='utf-8', newline='')
        i = 0
        for p in ls(path):
            if p[-4:] not in ['.avi','.mp4','webm']: continue
            sys.stdout.write("%d      \r" % (i))
            sys.stdout.flush()

            abspath = os.path.abspath(path+'/'+p)
            if os.path.isdir(abspath):
                print('skipping', p)
                continue
            ret, result = get_info(abspath)
            if ret == None:
                print('failed, maybe only audio!')
                continue
            vid_data[p] = ret
            raw.write(abspath+'\n')
            raw.write(result.replace('\n\n','\n')+'\n\n--------------------\n\n')

            i+=1
        # saves the data
        open(sys.argv[1]+"\\xstacked\\vid_data.nogit.txt",'w', encoding='utf8').write(dirtyformat(vid_data))
    else:
        vid_data = eval(open(sys.argv[1]+"\\xstacked\\vid_data.nogit.txt", encoding='utf8').read())
        print('imported', len(vid_data))

    dic_with_audio = {k:data for k,data in vid_data.items() if data['audio'] != '-'}


    total = sum([data['duration'] for k, data in dic_with_audio.items()])


    print('total', time.strftime('%M:%S', time.gmtime(float(total))))

    write_html(vid_data)
    print("###### PLEASE CHECK IF ALL FILES GOT AUDIO FIRST ! ######")

    if segments_limit:
        print('segments_limit is ON, limiting to 15 files')
        vid_data_items = [(k,v) for k,v in vid_data.items()]
        vid_data = {k:v for k,v in vid_data_items[:15]}
    return vid_data

# re-encode video with width 360, framerate 30
def re_encode(data, new_folder):
    path = data['path']
    resize = False
    if int(data['dim'].split('x')[0]) > 500 and float(data['ratio']) < 1.8:
        resize = True

    args = [ffmpeg, '-i', path,] + "-r 30 -vf scale=540:-2".split() + [new_folder+data['filename']]

    subprocess.run(args)

# put n in the array with the smallest sum
def pickput(gr, n):
    sums = [(i,sum([t[0] for t in a])) for i,a in enumerate(gr)]
    smallest = sorted(sums, key = lambda a: a[1])[0][0] # oh cheesus
    gr[smallest].append(n)

# balance videos to minimize "holes" at the end
def balanced_sums(vid_data):
    durs = []
    for filename, data in vid_data.items():
        t = data['dur']
        t = int(t.split(':')[0])*60 + int(t.split(':')[1])
        durs.append((t, filename))
    durs.sort()
    gr = [[],[],[],[]]
    i = 0
    while len(durs):
        n = durs.pop()
        pickput(gr,n)
        i+=1

    f = open(sys.argv[1]+'\\xstacked\\vid_data-balanced.nogit.txt','w', encoding='utf8')
    for a in gr:
        f.write(repr((sum([t[0] for t in a]), [t[0] for t in a]))+'\n')
    f.write('\n\n---\n\n')

    random.seed(433)
    for a in gr:
        random.shuffle(a)

    for a in gr:
        f.write(repr((sum([t[0] for t in a]), [t[0] for t in a]))+'\n')

        for t in a:
            f.write(repr(t)+'\n')
        f.write('\n\n\n')

    remade =  [[((j+1)*100+i, t[1], t[0]) for i,t in enumerate(a)] for j,a in enumerate(gr)]
    return remade

# build the xstack command arguments
def xstack(dic, mute = [], clean = False, lst = True):
    # target folder
    folder = next(iter(dic.values()))['path']
    folder = os.path.dirname(folder)

    folder+='\\xstacked\\'
    if not os.path.exists(folder):
        os.makedirs(folder)

    args = ['ffmpeg.exe'] if clean else [ffmpeg, '-report']
    # balancing into 4 list with alsmost similar length, to reduce end-of-video "holes"
    if False:
        dic = {a:b for a,b in dic.items() if float(b['framerate'].split()[0]) < 40}
        removed = {a:b for a,b in dic.items() if float(b['framerate'].split()[0]) >= 40}
        print('removed',len(removed))

        for a,b in dic.items():
            print(b['framerate'],',', float(b['framerate'].split()[0])<40)

        for a,b in removed.items():
            print('removed', b['filename'])
    balanced = balanced_sums(dic)
    # inputs
    backmap = {} # to track the id ffmpeg will assign to inputs
    j = 0
    filelist = open(sys.argv[1]+'\\xstacked\\filelist.nogit.txt','w', encoding='utf-8')

    for li in balanced:
        for i,k, dur in li:
            backmap[k] = j # tracking video id because ffmpeg use an ordered list of id as aliases
            if not lst:
                args += ['-i', 'file%d.mp4'%j] if clean else ['-i', '%s'%dic[k]['path']] # I swear this is a coincidence. Let's be honest why this script exists
            filelist.write('file "%s"\n'%dic[k]['path'])
            j+=1
    filelist.close()
    # this works, I tried many things. look at the docs. ow is output width, so guess the rest. setsar will set the sample aspect ratio to 1.
    letterbox = 'scale=480:270:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=480:270:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setsar=1, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS'
    # xstack argument with the layout
    # 2x2
    # xstack = "[concat0][concat1][concat2][concat3]xstack=inputs=4:layout=0_0|w0_0|0_h0|w0_h0"
    xstack = "[cct0][cct1][cct2][cct3]xstack=inputs=4:layout=0_0|w0_0|0_h0|w0_h0"

    # 4x4
    # applying letterbox BEFORE the concatenate stage. those are the 4 "list" from the balanced output
    # rescalers = ['','','','']
    rescalers = []
    for v,i in backmap.items():
        # print(v,i)
        vol = ''
        for a in mute:
            if a in v:
                vol = 'volume=0.01,'
                print('muting', v)
                break
        # testing with both audio and video to avoid desync
        rescalers.append("[rsclbf%d]fps=24[rscl%d];[%d]%s%s[rsclbf%d];"%(i,i,i, vol, letterbox, i))
    # don't really worry if the ids magically seem to be ordered when they should not, it's because tralala look at the code you know?
    concats = ['','','',''] # 16
    for quad, li in enumerate(balanced):
        concats[quad] = ''.join(["[rscl%d]"%(backmap[v]) for i,v,dur in li])+'concat=n=%d[cct%d];'%(len(li),quad)

    if lst:
        args +=['-i', folder+'filelist.nogit.txt']

    open(folder+'filter_complex_script.txt', 'w',encoding='utf8').write(''.join(rescalers)+''.join(concats)+xstack)

    args+=['-filter_complex_script', f'{folder}filter_complex_script.txt']
    args+=['output.mp4'] if clean else [folder+'xstacked-%s.mp4'%shortdate()]

    cmds = open(argv[1]+'\\xstacked\\ffmpeg-command.nogit.txt','w', encoding='utf8')
    cmds_d = open(argv[1]+'\\xstacked\\ffmpeg-debug.nogit.txt','w', encoding='utf8')

    cmds.write('\n'.join([repr(a)+',' for a in args]))
    cmds_d.write('\n'.join(args))
    if clean: return
    print(args)
    subprocess.run(args, cwd=folder)

def mix_audio(dic, balanced, stacked):

    backmap = {} # to track the id ffmpeg will assign to inputs
    j = 0
    clean = False
    args = [ffmpeg, '-report']

    for li in balanced:
        for i,k, dur in li:
            backmap[k] = j # tracking video id because ffmpeg use an ordered list of id as aliases
            args += ['-i', 'file%d.mp4'%j] if clean else ['-i', '%s'%dic[k]['path']] # I swear this is a coincidence. Let's be honest why this script exists
            j+=1

    stk_id = len(backmap)

    args += ['-i', stacked]
    concats_a = ['', '', '', '']

    for quad, li in enumerate(balanced):
        concats_a[quad] = ''.join(
        ["[%d:a]"%(backmap[v]) for i,v,dur in li])+'concat=n=%d:v=0:a=1[cct_a%d];'%(len(li),quad)
    amix = '[cct_a0][cct_a1][cct_a2][cct_a3]amix=inputs=4[all_aud]'

    args += ['-filter_complex']
    args += [''.join(concats_a)+amix]
    args += [
        '-map', '%d:v'%stk_id,
        '-map',
        '[all_aud]',
        '-c:v', 'copy',

        ]
    args += [stacked.replace('.mp4','')+"_aud.mp4"]

    cmds2 = open(sys.argv[1]+'\\xstacked\\ffmpeg-command_aud.nogit.txt','w', encoding='utf8')
    cmds2.write('\n'.join([repr(a)+',' for a in args]))

    proc = subprocess.run(args)

# this calls ffprobe on all video files is 'scan' is in the command.
# if not it assumes scan was already done and read from a cache file


if len(sys.argv) >1:
    folder = sys.argv[1]
    print(folder)
    folder+='\\xstacked\\'
    if not os.path.exists(folder):
        os.makedirs(folder)

vid_data = gather_vid_info(argv[1], stage, segments_limit = 'segments_limit' in sys.argv)

if "audio_check" in sys.argv:
    dic_with_audio = {k:data for k,data in vid_data.items() if data['audio'] != '-'}
    print('vid_data', len(vid_data))
    print('dic_with_audio', len(dic_with_audio))
    vid_data = dic_with_audio

if len(sys.argv) <3: exit('must have have args: <path> <convert|balance|scan|mix_audio>')
print('''remember, mix audio must be provided with a filepath''')


def fix_sar_dar(path):
    # old function to deal with exotic SAR/DAR values
    'ffmpeg -i <input> -vf scale=720x406,setdar=16:9 <output>'
    args = [ffmpeg]
    args+=['-i', path, '-vf', 'scale=640x360',os.path.dirname(path)+'/DONE2.mp4' ]
    subprocess.run(args)

def mute_audio(path):
    args = [ffmpeg]
    args+=['-i', path, '-filter:a', 'volume=0',os.path.dirname(path)+'/'+os.path.basename(path)+'muted.mp4' ]
    subprocess.run(args)

muted = []
if stage == 'convert':
    xstack(vid_data, muted, clean='clean' in sys.argv, lst=False)
elif stage == 'balance':
    bal = balanced_sums(vid_data)
    for l in bal:
        for a in l:
            print((a[0],a[2],a[1]))
elif stage == 'mute':
    mute_audio(sys.argv[3])
elif stage == 'mix_audio':
    bal = balanced_sums(vid_data)
    mix_audio(vid_data, bal, sys.argv[-1])
elif stage == 'custom':
    fix_sar_dar(argv[3])
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not take the time to test it since I removed dependencies. It's fixed. I tested it on a few video files and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

You should not alias `from os import listdir as ls` and `from shutil import copyfile as cp`, but also you just shouldn't be using `os.listdir` at all. Use `pathlib.Path` methods instead.

Requiring that these executables exist at the root of the drive:

```
ffmpeg = r"c:/ffmpeg.exe"
ffprobe = r"c:/ffprobe.exe"
```

is quite inconvenient for your users. Instead, use [`shutil.which()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.which) to find the location of those executables from the operating system's search paths. And don't leave the executables in `C:\`; put them somewhere in a proper program path like `C:\Program Files\ffmpeg` and include that in `PATH`.

You have a `USAGE` comment block - that would be better translated to a help string included in `argparse`. Use `argparse` instead of one-off checks in `argv`.

Add PEP484 typehints to your function signatures.

`for unit in` should use a tuple and not a list.

When comparing to `< 1024.0` there's no need to write it as a float.

`"%.1f"%num` is better-expressed with string interpolation as `f'{num:.1f}'`. Same with `"%s %s%s" %` and so on.

`sizeof_fmt` doesn't need to loop. Just [log10](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.log10) to find the number of digits. Do not have `Y` as a special case; it should be in the format sequence with the other characters.

`html_start` and its markup should go away. This is a job for [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/).

`shfn` is not a good name; I have no idea what that function does.

`subprocess.run` should be replaced with `subprocess.check_output`.

Do not `eval`, and *especially do not `eval` from the untrusted output of another process*. This is disastrous from a security point of view, but is also not maintainable.

`if False: # spamming the terminal` should be replaced with a call to the official Python logger module. If you don't want this output to be shown for normal operation, demote it to the debug level so that it will only be shown if you change the logger level to debug.

`time.strftime('%M:%S', time.gmtime` should be replaced with `datetime` module equivalents.

Delete dead code like this:

```
# ret['dur'] = time.strftime('%M:%S', time.gmtime(float(video['duration'])))
# ret['dur'] = time.strftime('%M:%S', time.gmtime(float(dic['duration'])))
```

If you're worried about keeping a history of code evolution, that's what source control like `git` is for.

Move all of your `import`s to the top of the file.

You should avoid hard-coding Windows `\` path separators. Based on context, these should either be replaced with `/`, or [pathsep](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.pathsep), or `pathlib.Path` `/` operators.

From `if len(sys.argv) >1:` onward, that code should all be in a `main()` function.

Addressing these issues will go a long way to making your code sane. I encourage you to work on it, ask questions as comments on this response if needed, and then when you're ready ask a new question with your revised code.

Comment: `shfn` shortens filenames I assume.